# R is broken with "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpcre.1.dylib"

Tags: r, installation, dylib, conda, dyld

I'm trying to follow [Brew doctor: dyld: Library not loaded & Error: No available formula for zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323252/brew-doctor-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-no-available-formula-for-zlib) but it isn't helping. I had my `R` working earlier today but I installed `r-essentials` through `conda` (how my `R` was installed originally) and am now getting the following error:

```
$ which R
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/bin/R

$ /Users/jespinoz/anaconda/bin/R
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I ended up deleting my entire anaconda directory and reinstalling :(**

***In hindsight***, I realized that I needed to make a shellscript just incase anything weird happened and I needed to reinstall everything again.  Everytime I install a new module that I think will be useful I just add it to here.

Here's all my `Python` and `R` packages:

```
# Python
conda install xarray --yes
conda install holoviews --yes
conda install seaborn --yes
conda install scikit-learn --yes
conda install scikit-image --yes
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/biocore scikit-bio --yes
conda install dill --yes
conda install pandas --yes
conda install numpy --yes
conda install networkx --yes
conda install scipy --yes
pip install fastcluster
conda install -c jjhelmus tensorflow=0.8.0rc0 --yes
conda install bokeh --yes
conda install BioPython --yes
conda install tqdm --yes
pip install git+https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3
conda install dask --yes
conda install numba --yes
pip install nbopen
pip install nbextensions
pip install https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tarball/master
conda install html5lib --yes
pip install selenium
conda install phantoms --yes
pip install pubchempy —yes
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/rdkit rdkit --yes
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda bioservices --yes
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/ales-erjavec orange-bioinformatics
pip install plotly
pip install ete3

# R
conda install -c r r --yes
conda install -c r r-essentials --yes
conda install -c r r-rserve --yes
conda install -c r r-devtools --yes
conda install -c r r-rcurl --yes
conda install -c r r-RJSONIO --yes
conda install -c r r-jpeg --yes
conda install -c r r-png --yes
conda install -c r r-roxygen2 --yes
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda bioconductor-edger --yes
```

Comment: It's happened on my work computer and my personal.  Same solution to both.  I got it down tho.  I made a shell script that has all of my modules that I need so I can run that and it downloads all of them.  Basically just like `conda install xarray --yes` next line `pip install fastcluster`, etc.

Comment: I solved this by "conda install -c r r-irkernel zeromq"from a comment of this stackoverflow question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387027/unable-to-load-irkernel-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 2):

The file libpcre.1.dylib  is not in @rpath

I found libpcre.1.dylib  from  /opt/local/lib/
and made symbolic link where conda put R's libraries, in my case

```
~/anaconda/lib/R/lib
```

If you have similar situation these 2 commands with few modifications should help you

```
cd  /Users/you_username/anaconda/lib/R/lib

ln -s /opt/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib libpcre.1.dylib
```

and then the problem got solved.

My gess is that when you have R already installed in you computer and
r-essentials are added later to anaconda insatll don't add the libpcre.1.dylib to installation because it already exists. But when finishing didn't update @rpath.

Comment: Thanks for help.  I can't try it again since it's already working but this will definitely be useful for other people.

Comment: `ln -s /opt/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib libpcre.1.dylib` broke this.  How can I undo this?

Comment: It broke my entire R :(