# Install and run R kernel for Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have jupyter notebook installed, I also have R installed. Both work fine independently.

When I run jupyter with `jupyter notebook`, then try to open an `ipynb` file, I see

[image]

The only option in the dropdown is Python 3 (R is not an option).

#### Question

How do you open a jupyter notebook with an R kernel (on mac)?

#### Note

- I tried `jupyter notebook --runtime-dir /usr/local/bin/R` but that was just guessing
- Looks like the R kernel could be [installed via `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open any R session (e.g. in RStudio is fine, or open terminal/bash and type `R` to start an R session).

Install the kernel with:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Close and reopen the notebook and the R kernel will now be available.

Comment: I have a similar problem. What prompt are you typing the above statements at?

Comment: It works for me from any R prompt, I had RStudio installed so I ran it from there, but another option is to open terminal, type `R` to start the R interpreter, and run it there

Comment: maybe also worth considering 
`IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE) # install system-wide`

Comment: credits to https://richpauloo.github.io/2018-05-16-Installing-the-R-kernel-in-Jupyter-Lab/

Comment: The additional advice at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42698032/6255436 were also useful

Answer (score 2):

If the R kernel does not appear as an option within a Jupyter notebook even after installing R, and one is using Anaconda, bringing up the conda prompt from the Start menu (Windows 10), and running the following commands may do the trick:

```
conda config --add channels r
conda install --yes r-irkernel
```

Credit to [this post](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/163#issuecomment-118106005).